# scriptコマンドを用いて10秒間のログを保存したい

Tags: macos, bash

scriptコマンドでログ取得を開始し、10秒後にexitしようとしています

```
#!/bin/sh    
script [ログファイル名]
screen /dev/tty.usbserial* 115200
sleep 10 ; exit
```

下記のような結果になってしまします。

```
Script started, output file is [ログファイル名]
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: 10秒後にログ収集を終了した後も、作業中のプロセス(この例ですと`screen`)はそのまま実行しつづけたい、という事でしょうか？ それとも10秒後に強制終了してしまってよいのでしょうか？

Comment: 10秒後に強制終了してしまいたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
script -c '(sleep 10; kill $$)& screen'
```

`-c`オプションがある`script`でしたら、こんな感じでよいと思います。`util-linux`に含まれる`script`でLinux上でテストしました。
まずサブシェルをバックグラウンドで起動し、10秒後に自分を`kill`するようにしておきます。その後本命の対話コマンドを起動します。

（`-c` オプションに与える引数はシングルクォートで囲っています。そうしないと`$$`が`script`を起動したシェルのプロセスIDになってしまいます。）

Comment: ちなみにmacOSのscriptには`-c`オプションはなく、ログファイル名の後にコマンドを指定します。

Comment: なるほど。手元にMacは起動していないので、Mac版の回答はどなたかお願い致します。